# are there any php scripts like smush.it to optimise images locally on my site?

Tags: php, image, optimization, compression

I have seen functions that can optimise images using smush.it for your website but they still call the actual yahoo smushit server.

Are there any scripts like this that i can install locally to compress images after a user uploads them.

Comment: It's not PHP, but you can give pngcrush a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are on a linux box, there is http://sourceforge.net/projects/littleutils/ which offers

1. Includes several basic file property query utilities.
2. Includes several file renaming utilities. Includes several lossless image file recompressors.
3. Includes several compressed file recompressors.
4. Includes a duplicate file-finding utility.
5. Includes a secure    temporary file creation utility.

if you are running wordpress there is even a handy dandy plugin, that works with it, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cw-image-optimizer/

*i am not using either of the above links but i plan to when i rebuild my current server.

Answer (score 1):

I recently forked a Php Image resize script and you can find it [here on GitHub](https://github.com/whizzzkid/phpimageresize). This will basically help you reduce the size of the image on the fly as well cache it for you. So this improves the load time of any specific page depending upon the number of images loaded.

for example on [my homepage here](http://nishantarora.in/) , I load around 20 images from facebook cdn for the header. Now since the images were large lets say more than 500x500, I was loading a lot of overhead and just re-sizing them using the width attribute of the  tag. So I fixed the width and re-sized them dynamically on page load.

So, earlier with page cache on the page size 2.8mb something on average, this was brought down by approximately 1mb saving me server bandwidth on each load, plus the load times were much faster.

The usage is simple enough, still ping in case something is not clear!

Hope I helped!
PS: I am trying a loss less compression on the fly which will reduce image size even further. Let's see what I get!

Comment: I'm interested... What did you get? ;)

Comment: @HighPriestessofTheTech: didn't workout very well... :(... still using lossy conversion

Comment: Bummer :( Well, I'm going to give it a stab. If I come up with anything remotely useful, I'll post it here... Don't hold your breath, greater minds than mine have tried :P